# Regex to skip 1 but allow n number of 1s

Tags: regex

I try to create a regular expression which skips 1 but should allow n number of 1s.

I tried using ^([^1])*)$

It skipped 1 but also skipping any 1s.

Comment: Do you mean `^[^1]*(?:11[^1]*)*$`? Please clarify with 1 or 2 example strings.

Comment: What about `\b1{2,}\b`?

Comment: Wiktor, Thank you, but it didn't work

Comment: ctwheels, I tried your regexp, it allows 11 but not n number of 1s followed it.

Comment: Any code works or not only as per some requirements. What are yours? Your question is way too unclear for the time being.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the question ctwheels

Comment: @BalajeeKs my regex doesn't match `1`, it matches `11`, `111`, `1111`, etc.

Comment: @ctwheels, It works. Thank you so much. Been spending an hour trying to get this work.

Comment: @ctwheels, what if i want to allow inputs having 1 like 21, 121, 1000. Any chance of achieving it?

Comment: Sure thing. The easiest is probably to simply negate it as such: `\b(?!1\b)\d+\b`. I've added this to my answer below.

Comment: Thank you so much @ctwheels, I was so close to achieving this but missed \d+

Comment: what about `grep "11"`? When it finds one "1", it says nothing, when it finds two times "1", it says something, and when it find more "1" characters, it just shows the line because when there are more, there certainly are two "11" :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/DL8ueq/1)

```
\b1{2,}\b
```

To match any number except 1, you can use the following regex:
[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/DL8ueq/2)

```
\b(?!1\b)\d+\b
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
1
11
111
1111
```

#### Output

Only matches are shown below

```
11
111
1111
```

---

### Explanation

- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
- `1{2,}` Match the digit `1` (literally) two or more times
- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary